# Where vs Which in these sentences

Tags: relative-clauses

can anyone tell me which one is the correct sentence in these two sentences?

> 1. New York City, *where* Jordan was born in, is in the United States of America.
> 2. New York City, *which* Jordan was born in, is in the United States of America.

Comment: Hi ! Welcome to ELL, this is not the right place to get your homework done, so please edit your question by adding some information like why you want to know thoose information. Thanks!

Comment: Hello ai5d0s1, welcome to ELL. Please add some more information as to what things you have done to get the answer of this question on your own and what conclusion you have drawn based on the things you have done, if at all you did something. Here we encourage people do some research to answer their own question and tell us about it.

Comment: Also, we don't normally say "Where he was born **in**", just "where he was born."

Answer (score 2):

If you use "where", you don't need any preposition, although you need them when using "which" in that sentence.
Its corrected versions are

- New York City, where Jordan was born, is in the United States of America.
- New York City, which Jordan was born in, is in the United States of America.
- New York City, in which Jordan was born, is in the United States of America.